# Cut 45 degree angle iron

Tags: steel, angle

Hey how do I cut 45 degree angle iron to join them, I used my chop saw but they dont fit? I can send some pictures of the cuts

Comment: Do you have access to a set square to check the cuts?  I bet they're off 45 degrees, or the saw wasn't vertical, or the stock may have moved during the cut.   Grandad said "check twice, cut once"

Comment: If you are welding them, you would want a gap anyways, if the gap is narrower at one end, so be it, just make sure the bend is 90

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, If you were intending to weld them together you have a few choices.

1. Cut them as close as you can with the chop saw and then grind each joint into the appropriate fit for the 90 degree corner.
2. Mark with a angle square and cut with a hand hacksaw. Touch up if necessary with minor grinding.
3. Use a power hack saw that has an angle clamp to hold the stock accurately and make the cut.

When welding it will be necessary to clamp the parts carefully before applying the arc and rod to start the weld bead. Expect the heating and cooling to make the parts move around some so the clamping has to be solid.

If you were just intending to make nice butted corners and be fastening the angle irons to some other surface such as a work bench edge then you will want to confine the cutting of the ends to the most accurate cut process would be the hand cutting or the power hacksaw.

Answer (score 2):

Abrasive chop saws make messy cuts to begin with and often have crappy fences.  Helps if you take it nice and slow. Probably you're best bet will be to grind or file it - a miter fence on a stationary belt/disc sander can do a nice job.  Those big horizontal bandsaws do a nice job, but $$$ & space can be prohibitive if it's not something you'll use alot.

Comment: I will also try that, to see if it helps